# Prove that there are infinitely many primes ending in either 1 or 9.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that there are infinitely many primes either ending in 1 or 9.

I think a good starting point could be to consider that there are only finitely such primes $p_{1},...,p_{k}$ and consider the number $m = (2p_{1}...p_{k})^{2} - 5$.

Not quite sure where to go from here. Any hints or approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that this is both (a) already proved somewhere on this site, and (b) not super duper simple (it may take quadratic residues). At any rate, it's a special case of Dirichlet's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: @euler1944.  Hover the mouse over the  space after your name on your comment. Some options  appear . The pencil symbol is to edit (but is good for only 5 minutes) . If you click on the X it will give you the option of deleting the comment.  Unlike deleted answers, deleted comments disappear into the empty set.

Comment: Intuition tells us, yells at us, that this should be true. But of course intuition is never a substitute for actual mathematical proof.

Comment: DanielWainfleet  Thank you

Answer (score 6):

One of Dirichlet's theorem states that if $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $\gcd (a,b)=1$, then the arithmetic sequence $an+b$ contains infinite many primes. Your task now is to find an example of arithmetic sequences that produces numbers ending $1$; and a sequence that every element has $9$ at the end. The result will follow using Dirichlet's theorem.

Remark: Dirichlet's theorem is a heavy weaponry, and I guess that there is more straightforward approach to your problem.

Comment: $10n+9$ and half the problem is solved $10n+1$ and we did the other half

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $q$ is an odd prime divisor of a number of the form $n^2 - 5$, then $5$ is a quadratic residue $\mod q$. By the quadratic reciprocity theorem  we conclude that $q$ is a quadratic residue modulo $5$.